# How to perform search which is older then 15min in elasticsearch-py

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana-7

i am using elasticsearch-py module , i want to get all logs which are less then 15 mins. from google i have compose like this for a whole day range but not working.

```
data = es.search(index='filebeat-7.2.0-2019.07.27-000001', body={
"query": {

   'match': {
        'message': 'SocketTimeoutException',
    },


    "filter" : {
        "range" : {
            "timestamp" : {
            "time_zone": "+01:00", #UTC
            "gte": "2019-08-13 00:00:00", 
            "lte": "now" 
        }
        }
    }
}
}
)

length= len(data['hits']['hits'])

for i in range(length):
print (data['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['message'])
```

but I am getting bellow error, Without the Filter my query works fine.

```
GET http://xxxxx:9200/filebeat-7.2.0-2019.07.27-000001/_search [status:400 request:0.116s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  test2.py", line 29, in <module>
    "lte": "now"
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py", line 660, in search
    doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 318, in perform_request
    status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, headers=headers, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 186, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py", line 125, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', '[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not correct, it needs to be specified like this:

```
data = es.search(index='filebeat-7.2.0-2019.07.27-000001', body={
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "message": "SocketTimeoutException"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "time_zone": "+01:00",
            "gte": "2019-08-13 00:00:00",
            "lte": "now"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution does not give any error, but i just realized , the  match only give me data which is 1 month old for the same day, let me check that one first then will carry on with this.